# How to apply a function to an input of integers in Golang

Tags: go

For example, if the input was this

```
1 3 4 5
```

all separated by a space, I want to apply the function of squaring each individual number then adding it.

I just don't know how to apply the function to each number. All I can figure is that I have to put the numbers into a slice then apply the function to each of the numbers. I have looked everywhere and can't find out how to do this.

in Python I just do it like this and I already put the values into a list called "n".

```
#The list is pasted from the initial puzzle
n=[10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 10, 10]

# The list is first squared
b = (list(map(lambda x:x**2,n)))
```

b becomes the new list where the function is done to each number.

Comment: What do you mean, "integers separated by a space"? Is it a string? In your python example you have something different

Comment: My bad I'll edit the original post. I already converted the values into the list in Python. In Golang, the input is just numbers separated by a space as shown above.

Comment: "All I can figure is that I have to put the numbers into a slice then apply the function to each of the numbers." - yes, that is precisely what you need to do. Which of these two parts do you have problems with?

Comment: Applying the function to the numbers, I don't know how to go about doing this.

Comment: It's actually very easy. `b := make([]int, 0); for _, x in range n { b = append(b, x * x) }`

Comment: Thank you so much, Is there any way to do this with a recursion instead?

Comment: Yes, there is, quite easy too. Let it be your homework :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if your integers are actually a string separated by spaces.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    numbers := "1 3 4 5"
    var n []int
    for _, v := range strings.Fields(numbers) {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(v)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            break
        }
        n = append(n, i*i)
    }
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JcivNd29Gzg

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
 "strconv"
 "fmt"
 "strings"
)

func main() {
stringwithnumbers := "1 2 3 4 5"
numberarray := strings.Split(stringwithnumbers, " ")

stringwithnumbers = ""

for _, number := range numberarray {
    numbernew,err := strconv.Atoi(number)
    if err != nil{
    return
    }

    numbernew = numbernew * 2
    stringwithnumbers += strconv.Itoa(numbernew)
    stringwithnumbers += " "
}

stringwithnumbers = strings.Trim(stringwithnumbers, " ")

//You can check the result...
fmt.Print(stringwithnumbers)
}
```

You can check the code and your changes here:
https://play.golang.org/